# Input String Was Not In a Correct Format String to Datetime

Tags: c#

```
using (SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("Purchase_Order_History", con))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Agya");
    sc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sc.Parameters.Add("@Invoice_no", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value);
    sc.Parameters.Add("@Date_of_Purchase", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Date_of_Purchase.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    sc.Parameters.Add("@Item_Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value;
    sc.Parameters.Add("@Seller_Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column3"].Value;
    sc.Parameters.Add("@Company_Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column4"].Value;
    sc.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column5"].Value);
    sc.Parameters.Add("@Unit_Price", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column6"].Value);
    sc.Parameters.Add("@Total_Price", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Column7"].Value);
    sc.Parameters.Add("@Discount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Discount.Text);
    sc.Parameters.Add("@Paid_Amount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Paid_Amount.Text);
    sc.Parameters.Add("@Remaining", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(lbl_Remaining.Text);
    sc.Parameters.Add("@Sub_Total", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(lbl_Subtotal.Text);
    sc.Parameters.Add("@Total", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(lbl_Total.Text);
    con.Open();
    sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

I don't know what is happening here I am getting this exception Input String Was Not In a Correct Format

[image: Check The Error Image]

Comment: Use your debugger and look at the date fields in your data grid.  One of them has an invalid date.

Comment: The date in datetimepicker not in grid.

Comment: Your question contains no mention of a datetimepicker.  Why did you paste irrelevant code?

Comment: I start my code with debugger and it's getting error on paid_amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting the date to a string with `Date_of_Purchase.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")`. But the parameter `@Date_of_Purchase` is of type `SqlDbType.Date`, not of a text type. Therefore, change the code line to

```
sc.Parameters.Add("@Date_of_Purchase", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Date_of_Purchase.Value;
```

(Assuming that `Date_of_Purchase` is a `DateTime?` and you checked that it is not null.)

Note: You cannot format a date when storing it in a date or date/time column. You have to format it when displaying it.

Comment: I start my code with debugger and it's getting error on paid_amount

Comment: I don't think `Paid_Amount` is of `int` type. Use either `SqlDbType.Decimal`, `SqlDbType.Int.Float`, or `SqlDbType.Int.Real`, depending on the real type of this column. The types of the parameters must match the types of the columns in the table. Probaly same problem with `Sub_Total` and `Total` and all the other price columns. Also don't convert to `int`, if they are not supposed to be int.

Comment: The Column is set to Int and also in stored procedure, what should i do now

Comment: Which error did you get? What is the value of `Paid_Amount.Text`?

Comment: ok listen the code is works fine now when i enter on discount field if discount field is empty then the error is showing

Comment: You cannot convert an empty string to an `int`! You will have to perform some additional logic and insert `DBNull.Value` when a field is empty or the number cannot be converted. If the table column is specified as `NOT NULL`, then this will not work and you will have to inform the user to enter the correct values. Note: It is much easier to have a class with your properties typed accrodingly and to use data binding. This saves you all the conversions. Google for data binding and winforms (or whatever GUI you are using).

Comment: I remove the convert.toint from discount after debugging now it's showing error on executequery :(

Comment: Stored Procedure Fields
`ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Purchase_Order_History]
(
@Invoice_no int,
@Date_of_Purchase date,
@Item_Name nvarchar(100),
@Seller_Name nvarchar(100),
@Company_Name nvarchar(100),
@Quantity int,
@Unit_Price int,
@Total_Price int,
@Discount int,
@Paid_Amount int,
@Remaining int,
@Sub_Total int,
@Total int,
@Selling_Price int = null
)
`

Comment: Every Thing Works Fine Now The Problem Was con.open()

Comment: Thanks For Your Help :)